# How to look for the largest number in a key value pair array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

How could I get the file that has the largest value in size. If I were to have an example like this?

```js
let files = [
{
 fileName: 'untitled',
 size: 3456
},
{
 fileName: 'New Folder',
 size: 234
 
},
{
 fileName: 'photos', 
 size: 23
 
},
{
 fileName: 'ruby files',
 size: 30
 
},
```

Comment: what should happen with more than one max?

Comment: there should be only one max

Comment: your data has a syntax error. also what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` loop to check the size:

```js
let files = [{
 fileName: 'untitled',
 size: 3456
},{
 fileName: 'New Folder',
 size: 234
},{
 fileName: 'photos', 
 size: 23
},{
 fileName: 'ruby files',
 size: 30
}]
var largest = files[0].size;
var fileName = files[0].fileName;
for (let i=1; i < files.length; i++){
  if (files[i].size > largest) {
    largest = files[i].size;
    fileName = files[i].fileName;
  }
}

console.log(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce :

```
let files = [
{
    fileName: 'untitled',
    size: 3456
},
{
    fileName: 'New Folder',
    size: 234

},
{
    fileName: 'photos', 
    size: 23

},
{
    fileName: 'ruby files',
    size: 30

}]
let maxSizedFfile = files.reduce((maxFile, file) => maxFile && maxFile.size > file.size ? maxFile : file, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will return you the maximum size in your files object.

```js
let files = [
    {
     fileName: 'untitled',
     size: 3456
    },
    {
     fileName: 'New Folder',
     size: 234
     
    },
    {
     fileName: 'photos', 
     size: 23
     
    },
    {
     fileName: 'ruby files',
     size: 30
     
    }]
    
    alert(Math.max.apply(Math, files.map(function(o) { return o.size; })));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by taking the object with the greater size.

```js
var files = [{ fileName: 'untitled', size: 3456 }, { fileName: 'New Folder', size: 234 }, { fileName: 'photos', size: 23 }, { fileName: 'ruby files', size: 30 }],
    max = files.reduce((a, b) => a.size > b.size ? a : b);

console.log(max.fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to sort the array by size and get the first, so you can do something like this:

```js
const  files = [
{
 fileName: 'untitled',
 size: 3456
},
{
 fileName: 'New Folder',
 size: 234
 
},
{
 fileName: 'photos', 
 size: 23
 
},
{
 fileName: 'ruby files',
 size: 30
 
}
]

const files2 = files.sort((a,b) => a.size < b.size ? 1 : -1);

console.log(files2[0]);
```

The strategy is to ensure you have a ordered list of files.